# Showing that $\int_{0}^{k} \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(k-x)}dx = \frac{k}{2}$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Let $f(x)$ continuous and integrable, $G(k) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{k} \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(k-x)}dx$. Show that $G(k)=\dfrac{k}{2}.$

(Hint: Let $u=k-x)$

Here is what I did:

$G(k) = -\displaystyle\int_{k}^{0} \dfrac{f(k-u)}{f(k-u)+f(u)}du=\displaystyle\int_{0}^{k} \dfrac{f(k-u)}{f(k-u)+f(u)}du$

Then:

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{k} \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(k-x)}dx - \int_{0}^{k} \dfrac{f(k-u)}{f(k-u)+f(u)}du = 0$

But now I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Have you tried adding the two integrals at the end, rather than subtracting them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$G(k) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{k} \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(k-x)}dx$ and

$G(k) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{k} \dfrac{f(k-x)}{f(x)+f(k-x)}dx$.

Adding these two, we get 
$2G(k) = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{k} 1dx$. So, $G(k) = \frac{k}{2}$

Comment: why when you change in the second integral from $u$ to $x$ the limits of integration don´t change?

Comment: @Wybie $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(a+b-x)dx$. In you question, do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $G(x)+G(k-x)=\int_{0}^{k}{1}dx$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subtracting add both..

$2 I = \displaystyle\int_{0}^{k} \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(k-x)}dx + \displaystyle\int_{0}^{k} \dfrac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(k-x)}dx$

What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You have\begin{align}2G(k)&=G(k)+G(k)\\&=\int_0^k\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(k-x)}\,\mathrm dx+\int_0^k\frac{f(k-x)}{f(x)+f(k-x)}\,\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^k1\,\mathrm dx\\&=k.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Hint put $x=k\sin^2(y)$ We get $$G(y)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (\frac{f(k\sin^2y)}{f(k\sin^2y)+f(k\cos^2(y)})k\sin(2y)dy$$ Now use $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$$ and add the two integrals and you get $2G=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}k\sin(2y)dy$ and from here you can get the answer.